# Shorten link before sending to Twitter

Tags: api, twitter, hyperlink

I have a PHP loop that displays different headlines and their links. I'd like to send those links to Twitter with an auto-generated short link via Bitly. This is how the link is structured:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=This is the headling {dynamic Permalink}">Share on Twitter</a>
```

How can I create a shortened link after the loop has created the actual permalink?

Answer (score 1):

You need to register at bit.ly and get the API key.

```
function make_bitly_url($url, $login, $apiKey, $format = 'xml',$version = '2.0.1', $history=1 ) {

    if(substr($url, 0, 7) != 'http://')
        $url = 'http://'.$url;

    $bitly = 'http://api.bit.ly/shorten';
    $param = 'version='.$version.'&longUrl='.urlencode($url).'&login='
    .$login.'&apiKey='.$apiKey.'&format='.$format.'&history='.$history;
    //get the url
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $bitly . '?' . $param);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    //parse depending on desired format
    if(strtolower($format) == 'json') {
    $json = @json_decode($response,true);
    return $json['results'][$url]['shortUrl'];
    } else {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
    return 'http://bit.ly/'.$xml->results->nodeKeyVal->hash;
    }
} // end: function
```

Now the $login variable is your login, the $apeKey your apiKey and $url is the long url, you want to be short and the function outputs the short bit.ly address.

More at: http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation

Comment: Thanks for your help, Mike. Not quite sure how to integrate the code you provided into my actual page though. Would you be willing to help me with a full example?

Comment: The integration is pretty simple. You just add this function to your code, somewhere at the top and then when you want to use it, just use it like this: make_bitly_url($url, $login, $apiKey);